# Using FPU return values in c++ code

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, nasm, x87

I have an x86 *NASM* program which seems to work perfectly. I have problems using the values returned from it. This is 32-Bit Windows using MSVC++. I expect the return value in *ST0*.

A minimal example demonstrating the problem with the returned values can be seen in this C++ and *NASM* assembly code:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" float arsinh(float);

int main()
{
    float test = arsinh(5.0);
    printf("%f\n", test);                    
    printf("%f\n", arsinh(5.0));             
    std::cout << test << std::endl;          
    std::cout << arsinh(5.0) << std::endl;   
}
```

Assembly code:

```
section .data
value: dq 1.0
section .text
global _arsinh
_arsinh:
    fld dword[esi-8]      ;loads the given value into st0
    ret
```

I can't figure out how to use the return value though, as I always get the wrong value no matter which data type I use. In this example the value 5 should be returned and I'd expect output like:

> 5.000000
>
> 5.000000
>
> 5
>
> 5

Instead I get output similar to:

> -9671494178951383518019584.000000
>
> -9671494178951383518019584.000000
>
> -9.67149e+24
>
> 5

Only the final value appears to be correct. What is wrong with this code? Why doesn't it always return the floating point value I am expecting from my function? How can I fix this code?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work* and *does work* is beyond my comprehension. *it works completly perfect, I just have problems using the values returned from it* is akin to saying *I can fly, only I fall when I try*.

Comment: Doesn't look compilable to me...

Comment: Then perhpas you should post the function `float arsinh(float)`

Comment: I wonder who upvoted such a riddle?

Comment: It compiles, but shows the wrong value. Only the last one shows the actual right value. Why is it necessary to post my assembler function? It returns a value in st0,(that's the only important thing for this question) which is only correctly displayed by the last output, all the other variations outprint wrong values.

Comment: You might want to return the value on the stack, or so [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322006/call-function-with-float-in-assembly-x86-x87#30324509) answer suggest.

Comment: I guess, first step for you is to stop equating *compiles* and *works*. Second step is to provide the expected result vs actual result and explain why expected result is expected.

Comment: Why post the code for `arsinh`? Because the code you posted reveals nothing.

Comment: The function calculates the area sinus hyperbolicus of a given float. The displayed values are: 1- 194.130431 2- 194.130432 3- 194.13 4- 2.31241 . The fourth value is the actual result of computing the area sinus hyperbolicus using another math library. All the other values are obviously not what I am expecting.

Comment: Stop right here and update it in the question

Comment: This question is rapidly getting closed. Please provide the "perfect" code.

Comment: @WeatherVane And upvoted for some reason...

Comment: That's a funny problem. Looks like something to do with the way you are returning the value in assembly.

Comment: How can the correct fourth result be from "another math library?" You call the same function. If not, you have posted complete fiction and expect a seer to find your bug.

Comment: It's not from another math library - it's the correct value calculated by my function. I just know that it's the correct value because I used another library to verify that that is indeed the value of the area sinus hyperbolicus of 5.0. (Which is what I meant by that)

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe it means that the result printed is equal to a result computed by a different lib.

Comment: @EugeneSh. mybad - trouble with unclear question / comment.

Comment: Just a guess, only in the last of the 3 calls to `arsinh` is the result sent directly to C++ style output.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, that's why I said it's a funny problem. why should it matter other than because of some quirk in calling conventions?

Comment: The problem is that the code is 100+ lines long. But all of that should not really matter. The only register I change is EAX and at the end of my function I clear the FPU stack completly and fld dword [result]. I can call the function 1000 times in a loop and it will always print the right results, but only using the 4th method, all the other ones consistently give me a wrong value.

Comment: Well, it could be some kind of undefined behavior somewhere..

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue is not that there is a failure returning a value in floating point register *ST0*, but in the way you attempt to load the 32-bit (single precision) float parameter from the stack. The issue is here:

```
fld dword[esi-8]      ;loads the given value into st0
```

This should read:

```
fld dword[esp+4]      ;loads the DWORD parameter from stack into st0
```

`fld dword[esi-8]` only works sometimes because of the way the calling function uses *ESI* internally. With different *C* compilers and optimizations enabled you may find the code fails to work altogether.

With 32-bit C/C++ code parameters are passed on the stack from right to left. When you do a *CALL* instruction in 32-bit code the 4 byte return address is placed on the stack. Memory address `esp+0` would contain the return address and the first parameter would be at `esp+4`. If you had a second parameter it would be at `esp+8`. A good description of the Microsoft 32-bit *CDECL* calling convention can be found in this [WikiBook entry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/High-Level_Languages#CDECL). Of importance:

> - Function arguments are passed on the stack, in right-to-left order.
> - Function result is stored in EAX/AX/AL
> - Floating point return values will be returned in ST0
> - 8-bit and 16-bit integer arguments are promoted to 32-bit arguments.

When dealing with x87 FPU instructions it is very important that the only value on the stack when returning a *FLOAT* is the value in *ST0*. Failure to release(popping/freeing) anything else you put on the FPU stack can lead to your function failing when called multiple times. The x87 FPU stack only has 8 slots (not very many). If you don't clean off the FPU stack before the function returns, can lead to FPU stack overflows when future instructions need to load a new value on the FPU stack.

An example implementation of your function could have looked like:

```
use32
section .text
; _arsinh takes a single float (angle) as a parameter
;     angle is at memory location esp+4 on the stack
;     arcsinh(x) = ln(x + sqrt(x^2+1)) 
global _arsinh
_arsinh:
    fldln2           ; st(0) = ln2
    fld dword[esp+4] ; st(0) = angle, st(1)=ln2
    fld st0          ; st(0) = angle, st(1) = angle, st(2)=ln2
    fmul st0         ; st(0) = angle^2, st(1) = angle, st(2)=ln2
    fld1             ; st(0) = 1, st(1) = angle^2, st(2) = angle, st(3)=ln2
    faddp            ; st(0) = 1 + angle^2, st(1) = angle, st(2)=ln2
    fsqrt            ; st(0) = sqrt(1 + angle^2), st(1) = angle, st(2)=ln2
    faddp            ; st(0) = sqrt(1 + angle^2) + angle, st(1)=ln2
    fyl2x            ; st(0) = log2(sqrt(1 + angle^2) + angle)*ln2
                     ; st(0) = asinh(angle)
    ret
```